# Make post request from Sinatra to Slack webhook

Tags: ruby, post, sinatra

So I would like to send a notification on a Slack channel we use at office when a particular call is made on our backend AP,[This post about sending a Slack notification when someone SSH's into your server](http://ryanbrink.com/slack-ssh-session-notifications/)

I tried Typhoeus, Ruby's Net::HTTP, and even Patron. It ran every time error-free but the notification just didn't go through. I wanna make a really basic post request. Something like below (I've tested this via curl in  Terminal for the same Slack channel):

```
curl -XPOST 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXXXX' -d ' {"text":"test"}'
```

For the gem's mentioned above, I referred to their Git documentation, and therefore haven't included any code snippets. Any help with performing the aforementioned task would be highly appreciated.

**Update**

After some more looking around, the gem Curb seemed to do the job perfectly for me. This is what I did:

```
http = Curl.post("https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXX", {:text => "bar"}.to_json)
```

The to_json was required by Slack API, which seems to expect stringified version of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/http'

url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXXXX"
uri = URI(url)
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)

req.body = "{'text':'test'}"
res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
  http.request(req)
end
res.body # contains the response body
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, Mehdi. However this doesn't seem to work. Gives me a 502 Bad Gateway error now and the error log on my server fills up with some lines of error messages that end with an EOF so can't even make any use of those.

Comment: 5XX HTTP codes means there is a problem in server side. [More information here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error)